# Names starting with 'the'

Tags: nouns, names

A couple of days ago, my friend and I were both reading and analyzing a Newsweek so we came across a some kind of strange grammar that I couldn't find a reason to justify. Here's the quote (the Newsweek, back in June 15, 2009):

> Steven Cook, who asserts that the Bush administration's funding of democracy programs in Egypt not only failed etc.

1. As far as I know names like Bush, Steve and so forth they wouldn't start with a **the** before the name itself. And surprisingly about **administration**'s apostrophe. Would we also use apostrophe with other nouns beside names?

In some paragraphs later, we found another strange one as quoted below:

> The Obama administration should learn from the fair but tough incentives built into the Helsinki etc.

2. The contrary as you see, the **Obama** administration here differs slightly in a apostrophe. why not using ***the Obama's administration***?

To sum up the questions, what I'm confused about are:

1st, Why Bush and Obama got added a 'the' before the nouns like `the Obama` and `the Bush`, why not simply `Bush` and `Obama`?

2nd, I'd like to know why the writer didn't use something like
 **Bush's funding administration** or **Obama's administration**, rather than that the names started with **the**?

Comment: _"Bush's funding administration"_ is meaningless in any context. The Saxon genitive in all of these cases applies to the nouns  (_administration,_ e.g.) and not to their modifiers. Likewise, the definite articles apply to the nouns, not to their modifiers (_Bush_ or _Obama._) _Funding_ belongs to _administration._ You are parsing the sentences incorrectly. (_Newsweek_ is a proper name and should take _no_ article.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your first question...

> Steven Cook, who asserts that *the* (Bush administration's) **funding** of democracy programs in Egypt not only failed etc.

and

> *The* (Obama) **administration** should learn from the fair but tough incentives built into the Helsinki etc.

The nouns used for determining article use are "funding" and "administration", not the names. You can leave the () parts out and the sentences are still grammatical and basically mean the same thing.

Regarding your second question, *Bush's funding administration* would have a different (and unlikely) meaning, since you changes the subject from *funding* to *administration*.

BTW, Newsweek is a proper name, so no article is used.

Comment: that was quite an explanation, let's see what ideas others have though.

Comment: @DevinHudson - user3169's answer is correct. Parse the sentences as he suggests, without the parentheticals, and you will understand. (_Newsweek_ is a proper name, like _Interstellar._ Would you refer to that movie as _**The** Interstellar?_)